# Javascript createTextRange(); issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

After excuting alert, next line gives an error.how can I fix this using javascript or jquery?

```
    for(var nI = 0; nI < aOrderNumList.length; nI++) {
        if(!isEmpty(aOrderNumList[nI])) {
            alert("Invalid Order Number");
            var oTextRange = $("#OrderNumList").createTextRange();
            var lFound = oTextRange.indexOf(aOrderNumList[nI])!=-1;
            if(lFound) {
               oTextRange.select(); 
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

HTML code

```
    <tr>
         <td>Order Number List:</td>
         <td><textarea tabindex="<%=nIndex+1%>" id="OrderNumList" name="OrderNumList" rows="2" cols="35" <%=VClass("OrderNumList","")%>></textarea></td>
    </tr>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Whats `OrderNumList` ?? What error you are getting ? explain more please

Comment: its a String array. these are the value in this senario  `[

"1181599"

, 

"1181913"

]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your code, you need to select text content of the input element (text, textarea type input fields).

**Java-Script**

```
document.getElementById("selector").select()
//selector is element id
```

**JQuery**

```
setTimeout(function () { 
    $("#selector").select(); 
}, 1);
//selector is element id, also can you with class selector ie. $(".selector").select();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
var oTextRange = $("#OrderNumList")[0].createTextRange();
```

createTextRange is a method of DOM object, not jquery object.

**Update:**

The createTextRange method is supported by the body, button, textarea and the input elements, but the use of the method raises an exception for some input elements (checkbox, image, radio). The isTextEdit property can be used to avoid the exception.

see more: http://help.dottoro.com/ljfahrpo.php

Comment: it shows this error `TypeError: $("#OrderNumList")[0].createTextRange is not a function`

Comment: you have to make sure $("#OrderNumList").length > 0

Comment: in here $("#OrderNumList").length = 2

Comment: I updated the answer, The createTextRange method is supported by the body, button, textarea and the input elements

Comment: seems this is not supporting for Other browsers except IE

Answer (score 0):

I echo what everyone else said, but do keep in mind that if this is the *only* thing you are doing, you don't event need jQuery.

```
var oTextRange = document.getElementById("OrderNumList").createTextRange();
```